# Set up R Global Environment with one script and access it with a second

Tags: r

I have multiple R scripts that need to run at the command line that all use the same global environment. Rather than each script loading the same packages and sourcing the same function file, how can I run an initialization script that will set up an environment that can be accessed by the subsequent scripts?

For (a very simplified) example:

Here's init.R:

```
library(some.package)

source(path/to/my_functions.R)
```

so I run,

```
Rscript init.R
```

at the cli. But then when I run my next script,

```
Rscript my.script.R
```

It creates its own global environment and I assume the environment created by init.R is destroyed when the script completes?

I've tried using save.image()/load() but this seems to be just as slow/inefficient as simply loading the packages and functions in each dependent script.

Can this workflow be made to work?

Comment: Why not just run `source(init.R)` from inside `my.script.R`? Once the contents of the file that you pass to Rscript are run, R stops running. You cannot leave data in memory because there is nothing running to claim it. If you don't want to save/load data, then you need to have one file to run everything you want (which can `source()` other scripts).

Comment: Yes, I absolutely could but I'm trying to see if there's a way to avoid that. I was hoping that by creating the environment with inti.R I could reduce overhead in each call of my.script.R.

Answer (score 0):

Just Rscript -e 'source("init.R");source("my.script.R")'

Comment: Hi H.Wang, welcome to SO and thanks for this concise answer. A few things could improve it. First, if you could explain a bit more how your code solves the OP's problem (e.g. what does `-e` convey?). Second, you could format your answer by wrapping code in "\`". Thanks so much, this looks perfect and will be helpful to others!